# Changing the key name in an array of objects of array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to convert current array to expected array using some code , but it was not working. I tried react/ javacript

```
Currernt Array 
[
{"name" : "john" ,"values" :["first","second","third","four"]},
{"name" : "sachin" ,"values" :["five","six","seven","eight"]},
]


Expected Array 
[
{"name" : "john","a" : "first", "b" :"second", "c":"third", "d" : "four"},
{"name" : "sachin","a" : "five", "b" :"six", "c":"seven", "d" : "eight"} 
]




const newArrayOfObj =  this.state.data.map(({
      values[0]: a,
      values[1]: b,
      values[2]: c,
      values[3]: d,
      ....
    }) => ({
      a, b, c, d,
      ....
    }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposal

```js
const data = [{
  "name": "john",
  "values": ["first", "second", "third", "four"]
}, {
  "name": "sachin",
  "values": ["five", "six", "seven", "eight"]
}, ];

const out = data.map(o => {
  return {
    name: o.name,
    ...["a", "b", "c", "d"].reduce((vals, key, i) => {
      vals[key] = o.values[i];
      return vals
    }, {})
  }
});

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this snippet

```js
``
const inputArr = [
  { "name": "john", "values": ["first", "second", "third", "four"] },
  { "name": "sachin", "values": ["five", "six", "seven", "eight"] },
];

const outputArr = inputArr.map((item) => {
  const newItem = { "name": item.name };
  item.values.forEach((value, index) => {
    newItem[String.fromCharCode(97 + index)] = value;
  });
  return newItem;
});

console.log(outputArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use two nested reducers. The first passes over the outer array of object, the second passes over the values.

I ran it in TDD style:

```js
it('transform array with array to enumerated object', () => {
  
  const current = [
    {"name" : "john" ,"values" :["first","second","third","four"]},
    {"name" : "sachin" ,"values" :["five","six","seven","eight"]},
  ]
  const expected =  [
    {"name" : "john","a" : "first", "b" :"second", "c":"third", "d" : "four"},
    {"name" : "sachin","a" : "five", "b" :"six", "c":"seven", "d" : "eight"} 
  ]
  const keys = ['a','b','c','d']

  function valueReducer(acc, v, i) {
    acc[keys[i]] = v
    return acc
  }

  function arrayReducer(acc, obj) {
    const valuesObj = obj.values.reduce(valueReducer, {})
    const newObj = {name:obj.name, ...valuesObj}
    acc.push(newObj)
    return acc
  }

  const transformed = current.reduce(arrayReducer, [])

  expect(transformed).to.deep.eq(expected)       // passes
})
```

Comment: It ran as far as I could see

Comment: I blocked the replay now

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick one here. Check if it could meet your need

```js
const array = [
  { "name": "john", "values": ["first", "second", "third", "four"] },
  { "name": "sachin", "values": ["five", "six", "seven", "eight"] },
];

const keys = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
const newArray = array.map(({name, values}) => {
  const newValueList = values.map((value, i) => ({ [keys[i]]: value }));
  return Object.assign({ name }, ...newValueList);
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

An one-liner:

```js
const inputArr = [
  { "name": "john", "values": ["first", "second", "third", "four"] },
  { "name": "sachin", "values": ["five", "six", "seven", "eight"] },
];

const outputArr = inputArr.map(({name, values}) => ({name, ...values.reduce((r, e, i) => (r[String.fromCharCode(97 + i)] = e, r), {})}));

console.log(outputArr);
```